# How do I install Windows 8 alongside Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, windows-8

I have seen a many questions about installing Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 8. I, however, will be installing Ubuntu 12.04 this weekend and plan on buying windows 8 sometime in the next few months.

I would like to know if I can install Ubuntu 12.04 now, and install windows 8 later without any problems. Every time I see how to install both, it is assumed windows 8 is installed first.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about this is to go to the following page [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) and see the comprehensive answer given there.

Answer (score 0):

Use gparted (or other) to make room for Windows. Install Windows 8 onto the new partition.

Then boot from a live copy of ubuntu,

once in ubuntu from terminal run

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

This should restore your grub boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

Is your system UEFI (and BIOS) or just BIOS. You have to be sure to install both systems in the same boot mode and how you partition also makes a difference.

If you only have BIOS or just want BIOS you must use MBR(msdos) partitioning not gpt. Ubuntu can use either gpt partitioning with UEFI or BIOS, but Windows only boots from gpt partitioned drives with UEFI.
Then you can just leave space or create a sda1, formatted NTFS with the boot flag for your install of Windows later. You may want to also have another NTFS partition for shared data which can be a logical partition. Windows only boots from primary partitions with BIOS and MBR(msdos) partitioning.

If you have and want UEFI Windows has additional partition requirements which you really should create in advance.

Windows Recommended UEFI-Based Disk-Partition Configurations

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744301%28WS.10%29.aspx

Both Windows & Ubuntu will use the same efi partition which should be the first partition on the drive.