# Installing Ubuntu under windows on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, system-installation

Is it possible to dual boot Ubuntu 12.04.3 and Windows 8, both 64bit?

Comment: It's possible but a lot of pain. Read this - http://askubuntu.com/questions/327835/how-do-i-install-windows-8-alongside-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: Some people have problems, and I have also. Make sure you read the install guide and understand what you are doing. Most, but not all problems arise when people do not take the time to understand what they are doing. erasing your windows install is but a mouse click away with the installer ;). Your question will likely be closed as it is overly broad, post back if you have a specific question or specific problem.

Comment: In short, I want to ask can I use WUBI for under windows Installation on Windows 8 64 bits with Ubuntu 12.04.3 64 bits ?

Answer (score 1):

I have used Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04 dual booted, and as of my experience there is not that much terrifying accept the fact that sometimes you wont be able to mount your harddisk in Ubuntu.

As of my thought it is due to the kernel session running in hibernate mode in Windows 8 even though the Windows is shut off(one of the reason for Windows 8 fast boot.)

Windows 8 turn off only the user session and keep the kernel session running in hibernate mode. Unlike full hibernation, only the exact system state and memory content is stored on disk using ‘hiberfil.sys’ system file and Windows can easily restore them and reinitialize the drivers at very next time you begin using your PC.